# append text to an output from command line

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking to run this command

```
asterisk -rx "core show calls" | grep "active" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

it will output a number but I want it to append a "0:" at the beginning so the output looks like this

0:{output from command}

any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo -n "0:" ; asterisk ......
```

Comment: This strikes me as the "most correct" answer, but it would be better if it showed OP enough context to see it working as a single compound command. IOW wrapped in either curly braces for redirection or `$()` for capturing.

Answer (score 3):

roll it all into [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
asterisk -rx "core show calls" | awk '/active/{print "0:"$1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `sed` on the end:

```
asterisk -rx "core show calls" | grep "active" | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed 's/^/0:/g'
```

by ^ in regular expression you indicate to put 0: in the beginning. You can add any text this way. Also you can add it in any other place inside a string, not only in the beginning.